# "No such column" error using peewee database in python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, peewee

I am making a peewee database. In my python code I try to retrieve rows from the model that may be empty:

```
player_in_db = Player.get(Player.name == player.name_display_first_last)
```

`Player` is the name of the model

`name` is a column in `Player` defined:

```
name = CharField(max_length=25)
```

`player.name_display_first_last` is a string

I then check to see if there are any rows in the `player_in_db` list:

```
if player_in_db:
```

I then get an error that says:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: t1.name
```

I can give you more of the error message if you need, but it's long and references a lot of peewee packages.

Answer (score 1):

You probably created your table without the `name` column. It's incredibly easy to check. Just open the sqlite3 shell and run:

```
sqlite3> .schema
```

Or you can use Peewee's own introspection methods:

```
db.get_columns('player')
```

Your model needs to (obviously) correspond to the schema in your actual database...